# Element could not be located error in nightwatch js

Tags: javascript, automation, client, assert, nightwatch.js

I want to confirm that each my string have text 'Operational'. Here is my code

```
module.exports = {

test: function (client) {

    var text1;

    client
        .maximizeWindow()
        .url('https://status.gitlab.com/')
        .waitForElementVisible('img[alt="Logo"]', 10 * 1000)
        .elements('css selector', '.component',
            function (elements) {
                elements.value.forEach(function (elementsObj) {
                    client.elementIdText(elementsObj.ELEMENT, function (result) {
                        text1 = result.value
                        text1 = text1.replace(/\s+/g, '')
                        console.log(text1);
                        client.assert.containsText(text1, 'Operational')

                    })

                })
            })
}
};
```

When I run this I receive error - `Testing if element <WebsiteGoogleComputeEngineOperational> contains text 'Operational' in 5000ms - expected "contains text 'Operational'" but got: "element could not be located" (5341ms)`

When I run without `client.assert.containsText(text1, 'Operational')` I receive full list of my strings

```
WebsiteGoogleComputeEngineOperational
APIGoogleComputeEngineOperational
Git(sshandhttps)GoogleComputeEngineOperational
PagesGoogleComputeEngineOperational
CI/CDGoogleComputeEngineOperational
BackgroundProcessingGoogleComputeEngineOperational
SupportServicesZendeskOperational
packages.gitlab.comAWSOperational
customers.gitlab.comAzureOperational
version.gitlab.comAWSOperational
forum.gitlab.comDigitalOceanOperational
WindowsRunners(beta)GoogleComputeEngineOperational
CanaryGoogleComputeEngineOperational
dashboards.gitlab.comGoogleComputeEngineOperational
```

Where is the problem and how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `client.assert.containsText(text1, 'Operational')` as this is meant for validating the innertext of the element. What you're doing is comparing two texts for which you can use a simple if- else.

```
module.exports = {

  test: function(client) {

    var text1;

    client
      .maximizeWindow()
      .url('https://status.gitlab.com/')
      .waitForElementVisible('img[alt="Logo"]', 10 * 1000)
      .elements('css selector', '.component',
        function(elements) {
          elements.value.forEach(function(elementsObj) {
            client.elementIdText(elementsObj.ELEMENT, function(result) {
              text1 = result.value.replace(/\s+/g, '')
              if (text1.includes('Operational')) {
                console.log('Found Operational in - ' + '"' + text1 + '"' + '\n')
              } else {
                console.log('Didn\'t Found Operational in - ' + '"' + text1 + '"' + '\n')
              }
            })

          })
        })
  }
};
```

Upon Execution, you can see something like this in console -

[image: Execution Screenshot]